# dc.js how to provide the total OVERALL column value using .group()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm working on DC.js charts and I'm trying to understand of how to create an overall "Total" variable of a column in the `dimension.group()` function. Lets say a column is called packages and its just integers. The dimensions is Area (North, South, East, West). When I develop the DC.js rowChart, I have to create the groups. Is it possible to create an overall total of package column inside the `group()` function?

Here is a simple create groups code below.

```
function createGroup(dimension, config) {

    return dimension.group().reduce(
        function(p,v) { 

            p.Total     += v.packages;
                /* p.TotalOverall = ??*/
            return p;
        },
        function(p,v) {

            p.Total     -= v.packages;

            return p;
        },
        function() {
            return {
                Total       : 0,
            }
        }
    ); // end of return
}
```

within the reduce function, is it possible to create a variable or object that will state only total overall package column? In the p object, I just want to add a total Overall package. I know there's a way using the groupAll() but I want my charts to have the total Overall Packages number (Object) available so I can display that in the tooltip, etc. This object will not change during the filter, I just need that total.

Comment: Something like [this](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_reduceSum)? group.reduceSum will sum the group.